# $\int \frac {x^{59}}{(1+x)^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \frac {x^{59}}{(1+x)^2} dx$

Just say $1+x=u \to x=u-1$ so integral turns out to be $\int \frac {(u-1)^{59}}{u^2} du$.

My question is how can I take this integral without expanding the term $(u-1)^{59}$?

Comment: Making substitution of $arctanx = t$ and then using reduction formula for $tan^nx$ is one way to go about this integral, however expanding that term is not that inconvenient

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to expand it out? Doing so is quite painless:
$$
(u-1)^{59} = \sum_{k=0}^{59} \binom{59}{k} (-1)^k u^{59-k}
$$

Comment: Let me clarify whether the intended integral is $\int \frac{x^{59}}{1+x^2}\, dx$ or $\int \frac{x^{59}}{(1+x)^2}\, dx$?

Comment: To clarify, I have $(1+x)^2$. And, I don't want to expand because of the my laziness @PrincessEev

Comment: The expansion is done in one line, as I did there. You're not obligated to write out all $60$ terms since there is a well-defined shorthand -- mathematicians are lazy too, after all.

Comment: Integrate by parts and think about the sum $1-x+x^2- \cdots +(-1)^n x^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving this integral you must have a $58$-degree polynomial plus a term $\dfrac{a}{1+x}$ and a term $b\ln(1+x)$ where the constants $a$ and $b$ must be calculated (we have $a=1$ and $b=59$
).

A careful observation in search of a pattern reveals that this integral has the form
$$\int\frac{x^{59}}{(1+x)^2} dx=\frac{x^{58}}{58}-\frac{2x^{57}}{57}+\frac{3x^{56}}{56}-\cdots+\frac{57x^2}{2}-58x+\frac{1}{1+x}+59\ln(1+x)+C$$ as you can easily verify taking the derivative in both sides.

Comment: In a more concise way we have
$$\int\frac{x^{59}}{(1+x)^2} dx=\sum_{k=1}^{k=58}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{kx^{59-k}}{59-k}+\frac{1}{x+1}+59\ln(1+x)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Define $\displaystyle I_n=\int \frac {x^n}{1+x^2}dx\ $ and notice $\ \displaystyle I_n+I_{n+2}=\int x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Considering you have $I_1=\frac 12\ln(1+x^2)\ $ the value of $I_n$ can be obtained by induction:

- sign is alternating because we have $I_n=-I_{n-2}+\int$
- for $n=2p-1$ odd then the terms $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ become $\frac{x^{2p}}{2p}$

Therefore we get in the end:

$$I_{59}=C-\frac 12\ln(1+x^2)-\sum\limits_{p=1}^{29}(-1)^p\frac{x^{2p}}{2p}$$

Comment: Ooh, you changed the $(1+x^2)$ to $(1+x)^2$ now this won't work. Still possible to get an induction though with $I_n+2I_{n+1}+I_{n+2}$, and calculate $I_0$ and $I_1$. The methods stands, but the result will be different.